# Keyboard layout on laptop is messed up after full system update

Tags: command-line, drivers, apt, keyboard, laptop

Keyboard layout on laptop is messed up after full system update.

Running Linux Mint 3.11.0-26 on an HP Pavilion.

Example of problem:

When pressing the o button it returns a 6, and

m=0, j=1, 0=/, etc.

Its only happening on right side of keyboard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it sounds like your keyboard has an integrated numpad or something. You can try to disable it by opening a "on-screen-keyboard" via the terminal and disable numlock from there.

Open the terminal: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and run `onboard`. When the keyboard appears on the screen, head over to the `123`-button and disable the <kbd>Nm Lk</kbd> button.

Hopefully your keyboard is working properly now!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had accidentally pressed `super + space` (windows flag and spacebar), this cycles through `text entry`'s `input sources`.

[image: text entry settings page]

(accessed from `System Settings > Keyboard` and clicking 'Text Entry' link)

Pressing it again returned me to English(UK) - note that the orange highlight does not actually select or set it, it can be 'selected' in this ui dialog but the keyboard shortcuts actually do the setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to : 'Language and support' then under 'Keyboard input method' select 'none' from the drop down menu. Mine was set to iBus for some reason and i had lost the £ sign altogether and @=" etc... All went back the way it was once i did this. But every now and again it switches back. So glad i figured out how to fix it!